# No bootable device found after install on already non booting Toshiba C650

Tags: boot, boot-failure

i have a Toshiba C650 laptop for a year and i had some problems with corrupted clusters in a partition and i tried to fix it by running chkdsk and change partitions which resulted into a not bootable laptop to windows 7. That made me decide to install ubuntu (an excuse) but still after many installs i get always a no bootable devices found during start up. The installation is flawless but no boot what so ever... I tried to fix the grub with boot-repair but nothing.

How can i see what is wrong? I suspect that the MBR is completely corrupt, is it true? Please help i don't know what to do :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Ubuntu?  My Laptop never works with the 'desktop' installer (the preview livecd) but always works with the 'alternative' installer.  It has the same symptoms, grub simply won't work and no attempt at recovering it succeeds.  Try that and see if that works.